# Magento: What causes re-indexing ... and why is it breaking?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, magento

**Background**

I have been doing some custom module development (in the Community folder) and have been making great progress.  My setup script creates a number of new Magento entities (and their database tables) and a few custom attributes.

I was working on front-end Product View customizations (which pull some information from my custom Entity database tables) and needed to create a few new Products for testing. ***When I went do Create (specifically, Save) a new Product all I got was a blank, white page.***

So, I checked System.log:

```
User Error: Some transactions have not been committed or rolled back
```

There are no exceptions, so I enabled MySql logging, and got something to the tune of:

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'XXXXXX.catalog_category_flat_store_1
```

[This StackOverflow post addresses this error ... kind of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19398361/magento-catalog-category-flat-store-1-does-not-exist)

**Efforts to Date**

Since my module creates a few database tables (and adds some indexes to them), I figured I must have done something wrong which corrupted Magento's indexing.  So, I installed a brand-new Magento instance ==> no problems; I can create/edit products just fine.

Next, I installed my module **but commented out all of my install-0.0.1.php (read: NO DATABASE MANIPULATION) except `startSetup()` and `endSetup()`** -- my plan was to go table-by-table and see when the `Some transactions have not been committed or rolled back` error reappeared.

Much to my surprise, however, **even though my module's setup.php did not touch to the database**, the Product Create/Edit problem immediately reappeared.

So, again, the only change that occurred between working and not-working was the installation of my module, BUT my module is not touching Magento's database.

**Question**

1. What might my module be doing to corrupt Magento's indexing?
2. What other problems might be causing this?

Thank you very much for any help or ideas!

Answer (score 0):

You have to require to Logout before to edit of the Product Create or Edit after added new module in Magneto admin ...

And after that it will still issue it occurs because of cache management issue ...